# Cross-Apply bad for a larger database or alternatives perform better?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, ssms

so 2 (more so 3) questions, is my query just badly coded or thought out ? (be kind, I only just discovered cross apply and relatively new) and is corss-apply even the best sort of join to be using or why is it slow?

So I have a database table (`test_tble`) of around *66 million records*. I then have a ##`Temp_tble` created which has one column called `Ordr_nbr` (*nchar (13)*). This is basically ones I wish to find.

The `test_tble` has 4 columns (*Ordr_nbr, destination, shelf_no, dte_bought*).

This is my current query which works the exact way I want it to but it seems to be quite slow performance.

```
select ##Temp_tble.Ordr_nbr, test_table1.destination, test_table1.shelf_no,test_table1.dte_bought

         from ##MyTempTable

         cross apply(

         select top 1 test_table.destination,Test_Table.shelf_no,Test_Table.dte_bought 

         from Test_Table

         where ##MyTempTable.Order_nbr = Test_Table.order_nbr

         order by dte_bought desc)test_table1
```

If the ##`Temp_tble` only has 17 orders to search for it take around 2 mins. As you can see I'm trying to get just the most recent `dte_bought` or to some `max(dte_bought)` of each order.

In term of index I ran database engine tuner and it says its optimized for the query and I have all relative indexes created such as clustered index on `test_tble` for `dte_bought` *desc* including `order_nbr` etc.

The execution plan is using a index scan(on non_clustered) and a key lookup(on clustered).

My end result is it to return all the `order_nbrs` in ##`MyTempTble` along with columns of *destination, shelf_no, dte_bought* in relation to that `order_nbr`, but only the most recent bought ones.

Sorry if I explained this awfully, any info needed that I can provide just ask. I'm not asking for just downright "give me code", more of guidance,advice and learning. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
I have now tried a sort of left join, it works reasonably quicker but still not instant or very fast (about 30 seconds) and it also doesn't return just the most recent dte_bought, any ideas? see below for left join code.

```
select a.Order_Nbr,b.Destination,b.LnePos,b.Dte_bought
from ##MyTempTble a

left join Test_Table b
   on a.Order_Nbr = b.Order_Nbr
   where b.Destination is not null
```

**UPDATE 2**

Attempted another let join with a max `dte_bought`, works very but only returns the `order_nbr`, the other columns are *NULL*. Any suggestion?

```
select a.Order_nbr,b.Destination,b.Shelf_no,b.Dte_Bought

from ##MyTempTable a

left join 
(select * from Test_Table where Dte_bought = (
select max(dte_bought) from Test_Table)
)b on b.Order_nbr = a.Order_nbr


order by Dte_bought asc
```

K.M

Comment: MySQL does not support `CROSS APPLY` so your question doesn't make sense.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `CROSS APPLY()` you can use `INNER JOIN` with `subquery`. Check the following query :

```
SELECT
    TempT.Ordr_nbr
   ,TestT.destination
   ,TestT.shelf_no
   ,TestT.dte_bought
FROM ##MyTempTable TempT
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT   T.destination
                    ,T.shelf_no
                    ,T.dte_bought
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.Order_nbr ORDER BY T.dte_bought DESC) ID
             FROM Test_Table T           
            ) TestT
            ON TestT.Id=1 AND TempT.Order_nbr = TestT.order_nbr
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying. I tried your inner join query and originally it comes up error for the "Where" clause so I modified it to have a "on TempT.Order_nbr = TestT.order_nbr" and then a "WHERE TestT.Id=1". Unfortuantely this was just as long to execute, if not longer. Any other suggestions? I even tried it with a left join there.